# Regex pattern for every alternate space

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have the following line

```
17 3 33 79 38 3 23 119 36 3 27 17 32 10 18 9 93 6
```

I want to replace every alternate space with a word, say `'x'`, so that it looks like

```
17 3x33 79x38 3x23 119x36 3x27 17x32 10x18 9x93 6
```

I'm using Python 3.

tried this pattern, but it is replacing every space

```
(?=\d{0,3})(?=\s\d{0,4})\s
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could define "every other space" as "every space that only has pairs of numbers behind it until the end of the string"

```
\s(?=(?:\b\d{1,3}\s\d{1,3}\b\s*)*$)
```

Breakdown:

```
\s            # the space we're going to replace
(?=           # positive look-ahead
  (?:         #   non-capturing group
    \b        #     a word boundary (don't match partial numbers)
    \d{1,3}   #     a number 
    \s        #     a space in-between (implicit \b)
    \d{1,3}   #     a number
    \b        #     a word boundary
    \s*       #     a connecting space to the next number pair (or none at the end of the string)
  )*          #   end non-capturing group, repeat ("only pairs of numbers")
  $           #   end of string ("until the end of the string")
)             # end look-ahead
```

To select the *other* spaces, you could add one `\d{1,3}` before the `$`.

---

But realistically, I would probably solve this without regex.

```
input_str = '17 3 33 79 38 3 23 119 36 3 27 17 32 10 18 9 93 6'
numbers = numbers = input_str.split(' ')

output_str = ''.join([n + ('x' if i % 2 else ' ') for i, n in enumerate(numbers)])
# => '17 3x33 79x38 3x23 119x36 3x27 17x32 10x18 9x93 6x'

output_str = output_str.rstrip('x')
# => '17 3x33 79x38 3x23 119x36 3x27 17x32 10x18 9x93 6'
```

or, fancier with `itertools` (although personally I would prefer the above):

```
from itertools import cycle

input_str = '17 3 33 79 38 3 23 119 36 3 27 17 32 10 18 9 93 6'

pairs = zip(input_str.split(' '), cycle([' ', 'x']))
# => [('17', ' '), ('3', 'x'), ('33', ' '), ... ]

output_str = ''.join(p for pair in pairs for p in pair)
# => '17 3x33 79x38 3x23 119x36 3x27 17x32 10x18 9x93 6x'

output_str = output_str.rstrip('x')
# => '17 3x33 79x38 3x23 119x36 3x27 17x32 10x18 9x93 6'
```

Comment: this is brilliant